OTEL: Log level overriding in .NET isn't working when LogLevel.Information is specified for a particular namespace or method
I am using OTEL (OpenTelemetry) for logging and sending logs and metrics to Application Insights. Here's how I'm configuring the logging in OTEL:
 public static class OpenTelemetrySetup
    {

 public static IOpenTelemetryBuilder AddOpenTelemetryDefaults(this IServiceCollection service, IConfiguration configuration)
 {
 if(options.LoggingOptions.LogExporters.Length > 0) { 
     service.AddLogging(logging =>
     {

         if(options.LoggingOptions.ClearProviders) 
         {
             logging.ClearProviders();
         }                
         logging.AddFilter("Case", LogLevel.Information);
         logging.AddOpenTelemetry(openTelLogOptions =>
         {
             openTelLogOptions
                 .SetLoggingOptionsFromConfig(options.LoggingOptions)
                 .AddLogExportersFromConfig(options);
             
         });
     });
 }
    }
}

I am calling above method from web api start up class.
 // OTEL
 services.AddLogging(logging => logging.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")));
 IOpenTelemetryBuilder otelBuilder = services.AddOpenTelemetryDefaults(configService).WithTracing(tracingOptions => { tracingOptions.AddProcessor(new CodeProcessor()); });
 otelBuilder.WithNoTracingForStaticFiles();
 otelBuilder.WithNoTracingForDependencyHealthEndpoints();

Appsetting Json File where i set the default logging levels:
 "LogLevel": {
       "Default": "Warning",
       "Microsoft": "Critical",
       "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Critical",      
       "MyNameSpace.MyMethod": "Information"
    }

OTEL itself also have its own setting.json file.

All warnings from MyMethod are being logged in Application Insights,
as the default log level is set to Warning. However, the
'Information' messages are not getting logged, despite overriding the
default log level.

My Method Log sample :
   MyMethod{
this.logger.LogWarningWithProperties($"message", properties); // Works

this.logger.LogInformationWithProperties($"message", properties); // Not working
}

